# how to remove certain records in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I am having a little tough time removing only certain types of records from the dataset

I have a dataset

```
name   |    dob   |resource id| resource name
John   |01/01/1999|243947     | Children Hospital
Paul   |02/05/1994|256935     | Own Home- Mother
Asheley|05/23/1988|256989     | Community Hospital North
Sara   |12/17/1996|258796     | Own Home- Father
Peter  |09/17/2002|256934     | Own Home- Parents
Tony   |03/30/1985|256569     | Pine Grove Hospital
```

I want to remove a certain types of resource ids from the data as I do not need these. In this case it is the resource ids which are a hospital of any kind. How would I code it within the same line? I have to do it using resource id column as I do not have access to the resource name. My results should look like this

```
name   |    dob   |resource id| resource name
Paul   |02/05/1994|256935     | Own Home- Mother
Sara   |12/17/1996|258796     | Own Home- Father
Peter  |09/17/2002|256934     | Own Home- Parents
```

I know which IDs I have to remove I just do not know how to code it

Comment: `dplyr::filter(mydat, stringr::str_detect(\`resource name\`, "Hospital", negate = TRUE))`

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `grepl()`:

```
#Code
newdf <- df[!grepl('hospital',df$`resource name`,ignore.case = T),]
```

Output:

```
     name        dob resource id      resource name
2 Paul    02/05/1994      256935   Own Home- Mother
4 Sara    12/17/1996      258796   Own Home- Father
5 Peter   09/17/2002      256934  Own Home- Parents
```

Or using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code 2
newdf <- df %>% filter(!grepl('hospital',`resource name`,ignore.case = T))
```

Output:

```
     name        dob resource id      resource name
1 Paul    02/05/1994      256935   Own Home- Mother
2 Sara    12/17/1996      258796   Own Home- Father
3 Peter   09/17/2002      256934  Own Home- Parents
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(name = c("John   ", "Paul   ", "Asheley", "Sara   ", 
"Peter  ", "Tony   "), dob = c("01/01/1999", "02/05/1994", "05/23/1988", 
"12/17/1996", "09/17/2002", "03/30/1985"), `resource id` = c(243947, 
256935, 256989, 258796, 256934, 256569), `resource name` = c(" Children Hospital", 
" Own Home- Mother", " Community Hospital North", " Own Home- Father", 
" Own Home- Parents", " Pine Grove Hospital")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

A way using ids can be identifying those records with match for hospital and then exclude:

```
#Create keys
Keys <- df[!duplicated(df$`resource id`),c('resource id','resource name')]
#Create vector of ids
ids <- Keys$`resource id`[grepl('hospital',Keys$`resource name`,ignore.case = T)]
#Filter
df[!df$`resource id` %in% ids,]
```

Output:

```
     name        dob resource id      resource name
2 Paul    02/05/1994      256935   Own Home- Mother
4 Sara    12/17/1996      258796   Own Home- Father
5 Peter   09/17/2002      256934  Own Home- Parents
```

Note that ids contains this:

```
ids
[1] 243947 256989 256569
```

You can also adapt with `own` to match other records.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Is there any other way to remove these records using resource ids only? I already know which resource IDs I have to remove. I just need to know how to code it :)

Comment: @Jay I have added an updated to test with ids and then exclude. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grepl` to match substring

```
subset(df1, grepl('Own', `resource name`))
```

-output

```
#   name        dob resourceid     resource name
#2  Paul 02/05/1994     256935  Own Home- Mother
#4  Sara 12/17/1996     258796  Own Home- Father
#5 Peter 09/17/2002     256934 Own Home- Parents
```

If it is based on 'resourceid', we can use `%in%` with `!`

```
nm1 <- c(243947L, 256989L, 256569L)
subset(df1, !resourceid %in% nm1)
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
      filter(str_detect( `resource name`, 'Own'))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("John", "Paul", "Asheley", "Sara", "Peter", 
"Tony"), dob = c("01/01/1999", "02/05/1994", "05/23/1988", "12/17/1996", 
"09/17/2002", "03/30/1985"), resourceid = c(243947L, 256935L, 
256989L, 258796L, 256934L, 256569L), `resource name` = c("Children Hospital", 
"Own Home- Mother", "Community Hospital North", "Own Home- Father", 
"Own Home- Parents", "Pine Grove Hospital")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` to get corresponding `resource id` from `"Hospital"` and remove them with `%in%`.

```
subset(df, !`resource id` %in% `resource id`[grep('Hospital', `resource name`)])

#   name          dob resource id      resource name
#2 Paul    02/05/1994      256935   Own Home- Mother
#4 Sara    12/17/1996      258796   Own Home- Father
#5 Peter   09/17/2002      256934  Own Home- Parents
```

You can also use the same code in `dplyr::filter`

```
dplyr::filter(df, !`resource id` %in% `resource id`[grep('Hospital', `resource name`)])
```